# Is there a way to put this navigation bar behind this custom background?

Tags: html, css, overlap

I am relatively new to HTML and CSS and I am making an application for school and my custom background is not meshing well with the background grid.
Here is the current code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Cool Hexagon Grid (interactive)</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="topnav">
        <a class = active href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('read') }}">Read</a>
        <a href="{{ url_for('create') }}">Create</a>
    </div>
    <h1>Cool Text Effect</h1>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class = "row">
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
        <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>

<style>

    *{
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #000;
    }

    h1 {
        color:white;
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 5;
    }
.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 5;
}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
  z-index: 5;

}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  color: whitesmoke;
  
}

/* Add a color to the active/current link */
.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #72bcd4;
}

    .row{
        display: inline-flex;
        margin-top: -32px;
        margin-left: -50px;
        z-index: 0;
    }

    .row:nth-child(even){
        margin-left: 2px;
    }

    .hexagon {
        width: 100px;
        height: 110px;
        margin: 2px;
        background-color: #111;
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%,
         0% 75%, 0% 25%);
         animation: animation 4s linear infinite;
         transition: 1s;
    }

    .hexagon:hover{
        background-color: #0f0;
        transition: 0s;
    }

    @keyframes animation {
        0% {
            filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
        }
        100%{filter: hue-rotate(360deg);}
    }

    .hexagon:after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 4px;
        bottom: 4px;
        left: 4px;
        right: 4px;
        background-color: #111;
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%,
         0% 75%, 0% 25%);
    }

    .hexagon:before{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        width: 50px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
        z-index: 2;
    }
</style>
</html>
```

I am expecting a seamless design with the background going behind the topnav,
any other suggestions for my code would be greatly appreciated I am still learning.
I have tried using z index but that was all I could think of with my limited skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to put your background in a div with the `overflow:hidden` property.
This is happening because you put negative margins on your .row class

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.topnav {
  background-color: #333;
  overflow: hidden;
}


/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */

.topnav a {
  float: left;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}


/* Change the color of links on hover */

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #5A5A5A;
  color: whitesmoke;
}


/* Add a color to the active/current link */

.topnav a.active {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #72bcd4;
}

.row {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin-top: -32px;
  margin-left: -50px;
}

.row:nth-child(even) {
  margin-left: 2px;
}

.hexagon {
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #111;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
  animation: animation 4s linear infinite;
  transition: 1s;
}

.hexagon:hover {
  background-color: #0f0;
  transition: 0s;
}

@keyframes animation {
  0% {
    filter: hue-rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    filter: hue-rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.hexagon:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 4px;
  background-color: #111;
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 100% 25%, 100% 75%, 50% 100%, 0% 75%, 0% 25%);
}

.hexagon:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.03);
  z-index: 1;
}

.background {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="topnav">
    <a class=a ctive href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('read') }}">Read</a>
    <a href="{{ url_for('create') }}">Create</a>
  </div>
  <h1>Cool Text Effect</h1>
  <div class="background">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
      <div class="hexagon"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```